# Using Multiple CASE Statements

Tags: sql, case

Is it possible to use multiple CASE statements to return side-by-side (same row) results? I've read through many CASE related posts, but don't see this specifically addressed.

I have 2 sample tables:
Transaction

```
RowID   TrxNo
1       12345
2       23456
3       34567
4       45678
5       56789
6       67890
7       78901
```

And Document

```
RowID   TrxNo   DocNo
1       12345      1
2       12345      2
3       12345      3
4       23456      1
5       34567      1
6       34567      2
7       45678      1
8       45678      2
9       56789      1
10      56789      2
11      56789      3
```

Based on these tables, this query

```
SELECT T.TrxNo
    ,CASE WHEN D.DocNo = 1 THEN D.DocNo ELSE 0 END AS Doc1
    ,CASE WHEN D.DocNo = 2 THEN D.DocNo ELSE 0 END AS Doc2
    ,CASE WHEN D.DocNo = 3 THEN D.DocNo ELSE 0 END AS Doc3
FROM [dbo].[Transaction] T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
[dbo].[Document] D ON D.TrxNo = T.TrxNo
```

Returns

```
   TrxNo    Doc1    Doc2    Doc3
   12345       1       0       0
   12345       0       2       0
   12345       0       0       3
   23456       1       0       0
   34567       1       0       0
   34567       0       2       0
   45678       1       0       0
   45678       0       2       0
   56789       1       0       0
   56789       0       2       0
   56789       0       0       3
   67890       0       0       0
   78901       0       0       0
```

I want it to return

```
TrxNo   Doc1    Doc2    Doc3
12345      1       2       3
23456      1       0       0
34567      1       2       0
45678      1       2       0
56789      1       2       3
67890      0       0       0
78901      0       0       0
```

This is my first post - I hope the information is presented clearly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you also need aggregation:

```
SELECT T.TrxNo, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN D.DocNo = 1 THEN D.DocNo ELSE 0 END) AS Doc1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN D.DocNo = 2 THEN D.DocNo ELSE 0 END) AS Doc2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN D.DocNo = 3 THEN D.DocNo ELSE 0 END) AS Doc3
FROM [dbo].[Transaction] T LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [dbo].[Document] D
     ON D.TrxNo = T.TrxNo
GROUP BY T.TrxNo;
```

Comment: I spent many hours trying to 'fix' this the way I wanted and hadn't considered aggregating to resolve it. Thanks very much for your quick, spot-on response.